# Executing web2exe from Golang is giving me 'exit status 2'

Tags: go

Im trying the following, to use go to bundle a folder of html files using the CMD web2exe.

```
cmd := exec.Command("web2exe-win.exe", "html-folder --main index.html --export- to windows-x32 --output-dir")
var out bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(out)
```

Comment: Capture stderr (or for windows, perhaps combined output) and print it in your error block (or directly set `cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr`). Sane commands should say why they fail to stderr when they exit with a non-zero exist status (except for when they clearly document what a specific exit code means, e.g. `grep` exits 1 with no output when it doesn't find anything).

Comment: Thanx Dave. Im new to go and didnt know how to get the Stderr. Now i can see my errors.

Answer (score 2):

When a program exits non-zero it means that it could not run successfully and typically it has written an error message to STDERR (or STDOUT).  You should somehow capture or print the output streams so you can inspect them for error messages.  For example:

```
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
```

Note also that your command line arguments should be separate array elements (instead of space separated elements in a single string as they are now):

```
cmd := exec.Command("web2exe-win.exe", "html-folder", "--main", "index.html", "--export-to", "windows-x32", "--output-dir")
```